# Group BY timestamp sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have a column having a timestamp like below. I want to group by according to month. I am using the query below.
but in a large dataset, it sometimes gives the wrong result.
I want to say is that any other way to use group by (per month) in that timestamp?

```
 SELECT count(distinct a) from abc GROUP BY (select strftime('%m', timestamp) as valMonth) where col1 like '%a%'

timestamp              a      co1
2020-01-23 17:22:57    12     a    
2020-01-23 17:26:59    12     a
2020-02-23 17:26:59    13     b
2020-02-23 17:26:59    13     b
2020-03-23 17:26:59    14     a
2020-03-23 17:26:59    14     a
```

Comment: I need to do aggregations which I have not mentioned here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use:

```
strftime('%m', timestamp)
```

then you group by month only, so the result would be for example 1 group for all Decembers of all years.
You should group by year and month with:

```
strftime('%Y-%m', timestamp)
```

So change your query to this:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', timestamp) AS YearMonth,
       ............... 
FROM abc 
GROUP BY YearMonth
```

Comment: yeah thanks one more thing if I need to count on the base of col1, see above example, then the about query omits the second month because col1 not like '%a%, I need it considers second month and add 0 as a result.'

Comment: @mayaali check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sgJtXUXKDtXb6sE5tBR6uW/0

Comment: BUNDLE OF THANKS